# modx revo вывод контента

Tags: javascript, html, css, modx, revo

У меня есть такое дерево ресурсов

```
О компании
-Факт 1(35)
-Факт 2(40)
-Факт 3(41)
```

в блок див пытаюсь вывести `[[+pagetitle]]` из ресурса 35
вот так:

`[[#40.pagetitle]]`

в див он выводит все правильно, но дублирует столько раз, сколько ресурсов (факт 1, факт 2, факт 3) получается дублирует 3 раза одно и тоже

Comment: Дополните вопрос. Как выводите? Где ставите `[[#40.pagetitle]]`, в чанке, шаблоне? Как вызывается?

Comment: в чанке [[#40.pagetitle]]
а в шаблоне вызываю уже чанк 
 [[!getResources:default=`Материалы на найдены`? &tpl=`firstf` &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tvPrefix=`` &includeContent=`1`]]

Comment: Вполне логично. Вы с помощью `getResources` перебираете все докумены, которые лежат в `о компании`, и на выход выводите чанк `firstf` (в котором видимо и находится `[[#40.pagetitle]]`). Так он и делает, находит 3 ресурса и 3 раза выводит чанк. Чтобы `getResources` работал с конкретным ресурсом, надо добавить параметр `&resources=`40``. Хотя лучше ещё раз обдумать, что Вы хотите получить, всё видимо гораздо проще.

Comment: все, спасибо, разобрался, установил пакет fastField и все вышло